# SPDX identifier for "proprietary" in Maven pom.xml `<license>` name

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, licensing

I want to add a license to the `pom.xml` stating that the project is licensed as proprietary, "All rights reserved.". [The Pom Reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#licenses) states that

> Using an SPDX identifier as the license name is recommended.

However there is no identifier for "proprietary" in the [SPDX License List](https://spdx.org/licenses/).

While [composer.json seems to go with](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#license) "proprietary" as the license identifier, and [package.json allows for](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#license): `"license" : "SEE LICENSE IN <filename>"`, i did not find any recommendation for `pom.xml`. Is there any?

Comment: There is no license which SPDX would identify under "proprietary", this is only a convention in Composer. I've added an answer that explains it a bit, and also why I think it does not apply to `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPDX has no identifier for "proprietary" in the license list because there is no such license.

Similar "All rights reserved." is not a license. Its the default for copyrighted works.

The convention in `composer.json` to use `"proprietary"` is an inverse effect: In the Composer project SPDX license identifiers were introduced relatively early and the *`license`* field has to use the **short identifiers** to build the license string (you can have multiple licenses in that field).

As the *`license`* field in `composer.json` then was defined by that, any other license not in the SPDX license list could not be named. As those are normally "closed software" licenses, the common term "proprietary" was suggested (all lower-case, no confusion with SPDX short identifiers which use upper-case letters).

The situation in `pom.xml` is different.  It does not *require* specific identifiers, it just recommends them for the *`name`* field:

```xml
<licenses>
  <license>
    <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
    <url>https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
    <distribution>repo</distribution>
    <comments>A business-friendly OSS license</comments>
  </license>
</licenses>
```

It offers its own system to name/define the license.  And to use the (long) SPDX Identifier for the name is only a (sane) recommendation, but naturally only if you're using a license from that list.

But if you *have* a license your own, you put its name and the uniform resource location of the license text in there.  There is no problem if you have an individual license (compare: in Composer you technically can not use the license field if you don't SPDX it)

Now:

According to your question you neither have yet a Name nor the Text of your license.

But you are already confronted with technical questions about how to incorporate and connect what is not there.  As you'd like to have a license (you want to add a license entry into the `pom.xml`), I'd say why not get help from a lawyer on your behalf that is able to find a textual expression of your proprietary wishes.  Tell her what you wish, want and need, like you want to fill out these two `<name>`and `<url>` fields and until then you just document the process:

```xml
<licenses>
  <license>
    <name/>
    <url/>
    <distribution/>
    <comments>Intentionally left blank.</comments>
  </license>
</licenses>
```

This certainly is only a very early and very basic baseline, you're certainly able to tweak it even before you consider grabbing the phone.

Comment: The first sentence isn't really accurate.  SPDX offers an "escape hatch" called a LicenseRef for this, and many other, situations involving non-SPDX-listed licenses.

Comment: It's absolute accurate, there is no license identifier "proprietary" in SPDX. Mind the quotes, this is meant verbatim as in use in Composer (and case sensitive), I guess it may have been received differently when the context of Composer is little known or neglected for whatever reason. Otherwise, why not? Provide a hypertext reference and I'd love to learn, my knowledge is more from the 1.x era of SPDX, and maybe I'm just not able to ctrl+f it in the list on my own ability: https://spdx.org/licenses/

Comment: Your first sentence was not accurate - proprietary licenses can be referenced using a LicenseRef. See SPDX specification version 2.3, section 10.1 [1] and Annex D [2].  Note also that the release of SPDX version 3.0 is imminent, and it retains the LicenseRef construct; in fact it extends the concept to cover unlisted license exceptions as well (via a new AdditionRef construct).

[1] https://spdx.github.io/spdx-spec/v2.3/other-licensing-information-detected/#101-license-identifier-field
[2] https://spdx.github.io/spdx-spec/v2.3/SPDX-license-expressions/

Comment: @Peter: But not with such a ref mechanism in the field in composer that takes the ids. That's the part you seemed to have missed. Accuracy requires context. There is no way to make use of a different license reference in Composer so far, it's only the license list with its IDs and a single exception, the named one. You may want to suggest that it should be different and I'm certainly with you that this could improve the situation. Is there something backwards and forwards compatible in SPDX since 1.0? Otherwise I read out of your comments a suggestion of 3.0, correct?

Comment: I'm not referring to Composer. I was responding solely to your incorrect statement that "SPDX has no identifier for "proprietary" in the license list because there is no such license."  This is 100% false, and has been since at least SPDX v1.0 [1].

[1] https://spdx.dev/wp-content/uploads/sites/31/2023/09/spdx-1.0.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer to this question is wrong. The SPDX specification offers `LicenseRef`s for this use case, so you could put a value such as `LicenseRef-acme-corp-proprietary-license` in the `<name>` field, and then a link to the full text of your proprietary license in the `<url>` field (to allow human lawyers to do appropriate due diligence).  Any conforming SPDX processor / expression parser should handle it just fine.

As of SPDX v3.0 (not yet released, at the time of writing), a similar mechanism called `AdditionRef` will also be offered for License Exceptions, which will make SPDX expressions such as `Apache-2.0 WITH AdditionRef-acme-corp-specific-modifications` possible.